# Проблема с созданием метки Placemark при работе с react-yandex-maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, reactjs

Я пытаюсь создать метку в компоненте с картой, используя react-yandex-maps.
Пока я не добавляю координаты для метки, приложение корректно работает, карта отображается. Однако как только я добавляю координаты для метки, получаю ошибку: TypeError: Cannot read property 'deserialize' of undefined.

Далее приведен код компонента:

```
import React from 'react';
import './map-block.css';
import { YMaps, Map, Placemark } from 'react-yandex-maps';

const MapBlock = ()=>{
    const mapState = { center: [59.939151, 30.329355], zoom: 16 };

    return(
        <section id="map" className="map container">
            <YMaps>
                <Map state={mapState} className="map container">
                    <Placemark geometry={{coordinates:[59.940000, 30.32215]}}/>
                </Map>
            </YMaps>
        </section>
    )
};

export default MapBlock;
```

Может кто нибудь объяснить, в чем может быть причина? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно указывать "coordinates", работает, если указать просто geometry={[59.940000, 30.32215]}. Видимо примеры, которые я смотрел ранее были не корректны.